# discord.py button events in cogs

Tags: python, button, discord.py

I want to make a button in a cog but I run into issues with the `@buttons.click` because I have not made a buttons client. But the ButtonsClient class needs a client argument. I have tried to make the buttons variable in the `__init__(self, client):` function which takes in a client. I tried to put the buttonsClient inside the init function.

```
class UserCommands(discord.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        # I have tried to put the buttons thing here
        # buttons = ButtonsClient(client)

    # this is where the error is occurring
    @buttons.click
    async def btn(self):
        pass
```

I use a plugin called [discord_buttons_plugin](https://github.com/SilentJungle399/discord_buttons_plugin) with discord.py.

[Pypi Project](https://pypi.org/project/discord-buttons-plugin/)

Comment: Which library are you using for the buttons?

Comment: I used this import: from discord_buttons_plugin import ButtonsClient